# Odoo13: Set a domain filter for a whole module

Tags: filter, module, odoo-13

I'm creating a new module for Odoo13, and my intention is to set the module so only users of OpenERP company (which currently has id = 2) can see the module.

I just created a filter in Odoo as follows (also tried many variations):

[image]

But it's not working :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the `id` not the `string` for filtration.

```
Domain : [('company_id', '=', 2)]
```

So to compare with this it will check the **company** has the `id` with **2**.